# How to make the x_labels appear for subplots that are on each other?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm learning how to create a dashboard to track my expenses. The first goal is to create a simple bar-plot that tracks my income and expenses for the two biggest categories. The code for the bar-plot is supplied below.

```
income = 5000
immediate_obligations = -1000
true_expenses = -2000
total = income - immediate_obligations - true_expenses

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=[1],height=[income],color = 'green',tick_label="Income")
ax.bar(x=[2,3],height=[immediate_obligations,true_expenses], color = 'red', tick_label=["Immediate Obligations","true_expenses"])
ax.bar(x=[4],height=[total], color = 'blue')

fig.suptitle('Spending Current Month')
```

The reason I went for three axes was to be able to color the income green, the expenses red, and the difference blue. The plots render well because they don't overlap. However the tick_labels only appear for the plot that is created the latest. It makes sense, but how do I apply the labels to the entire plot?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `color` [does not have to be a single color](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar). You can pass an array with the color of each bar. Therefore your output can be a achieved using only one call to `bar()`:

```
income = 5000
immediate_obligations = -1000
true_expenses = -2000
total = income - immediate_obligations - true_expenses

bars = [income, immediate_obligations, true_expenses, total]
colors = ['g','r','r','b']
labels = ['Income','Immediate obligations','True expenses','Total']

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=range(len(bars)), height=bars, color=colors, tick_label=labels)
fig.suptitle('Spending Current Month')
```